# Android - Get Place Name through Lat and Long values

Tags: android, geolocation

I need to check if there is any place (e.g. coffe, bar, business center, etc.) registered at a specific Lat&Long values or nearby and get the name of those places. Does anyone know how can I do such a thing in Android?

Tks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 2):

There are some possible libraries/services you could use to get geolocation support for your app. I only tried out gisgraphy.

- [The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) - uses Google services.
- [gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) - uses open streetmap, free to use if "personnal,non commercial and non profit one AND in a smart way". You can set up your own gisgraphy server if you want for free. Provides a REST API or a java library to use in your project.
- [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) - an read-only API for openstreetmap servers. You could also set up your own server or use one of the [services in the osm wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Applications) if it fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/).